# TypeScript: Deserialize from JSON to Discriminated Union

Tags: typescript, serialization, discriminated-union

Given the Typescript code snippet:

```
class Excel {
    Password: string;
    Sheet: number;
}

class Csv {
    Separator: string;
    Encoding: string;
}

type FileType = Excel | Csv

let input = '{"Separator": ",", "Encoding": "UTF-8"}';

let output = Object.setPrototypeOf(JSON.parse(input), FileType.prototype)   // error!
```

In TypeScript/Javascript, to deserialize from JSON, one can use `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, the second parameter of which requires a "prototype". With classes, e.g. `Excel`, one can just do `Excel.prototype`. But with Discriminated Union as above, I encountered an error:

```
error TS2693: 'FileType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

#### Question:

1. Is there any way to deserialize a Discriminated Union in TypeScript?
2. If not, is there any other **elegant** way to realize the scenario above (given two classes: `Excel`/`Csv` and JSON string serializing either of them; get back the correct instantiated object), regardless of whatever tricks, classes, class inheritance, interface, discriminated union or not...?

#### Environment

- Typescript v2.9.2
- Visual Studio Code v1.25.1

#### My try

```
let json = JSON.parse(input);
let output: FileType | null = null;
if (json["Separator"]) {
    console.log("It's csv");
    output = Object.setPrototypeOf(json, Csv.prototype)
} else if (json["Password"]) {
    console.log("It's excel");
    output = Object.setPrototypeOf(json, Excel.prototype)
} else {
    console.log("Error");
}
```

It's easy to recognize that this approach is cumbersome (`if else` alot), especially when adding new classes. Additionally, developers have to choose a unique field for checking in each class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `FileType` is not a class, it is only a compile-time union type.   No runtime code is generated for `FileType`, so while the type checker understands what it means, there is no `FileType` object defined at runtime to retrieve the `protoptype` property from.

I'm not clear why you need to set the prototype of the deserialized object in the first place.   Why not just declare it this way:

```
let output = JSON.parse(input) as FileType;
if (IsExcel(output)) { /* do stuff with output.Password & .Sheet */ }
else { /* do stuff with output.Seperator and .Encoding }
```

IsExcel() is to determine if the deserialized object is of the Excel type, it should be written as a [User-Defined Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), but it might be something like

```
function IsExcel(f: FileType): f is Excel { . . . }
```

IsExcel returns a boolean, but by writing the return type this way TypeScript understands it is reading the discriminator for the discriminated union.  You can check any way you want, for example by checking if `(<any>f).Sheet` is defined.

Comment: The problem is that the `as FileType` cast does not fail if one of the type properties is invalid; e.g. "xcel_doc" instead of "excel_doc".

Comment: @phatmann, the user-defined type guard IsExcel() would have to be written preform any desired checking of the presence of required properties.

Comment: isExcel would incorrectly fail if the type was misspelled.I hope one day we can get compile time checking of discriminating unions in JSON.

Comment: I'm afraid that may be beyond what compile-time checking can do, it seems like it requires runtime-checking.  You might open a new question on the topic.